# PHP read CSV file line by lines

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file loaded from an URL, and I want to loop over the lines with PHP.

Here is a typical line of this CSV:

```
1004000018;active;"TEST1";"TEST2";"TEST3";"TEST4"
```

I would like to get this result, for each row:

```
1004000018
active
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
TEST4
```

Comment: So look at using the [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function with a `;` separator

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can achieve this using the php function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), this should work :

**PHP**

```
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   //$line[0] = '1004000018' in first iteration
   print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Why don't you use fgetcsv() instead of explode().... one less operation, a function designed specifically to handle the other subtle nuances of CSV (such as quoted strings, and the separator appearing inside an actual value)

Comment: @chouaib23 i edited the post using fgetcsv, now you can access the variable $line as an array, for instance : $line[0] in the first iteration will be equal to $line[0] = '1004000018';

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved

Comment: In order to get an array, you need delimiter of ";" passed to the fgetcsv, in the example above.

Comment: Does this line `$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');` load the entire file into memory?

Comment: @Pankaj No. Both `file` and `file_get_contents` load the file in-memory. `fopen` gives us control to read/write on specific parts of the file only. Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 2):

This will help you for read csv:

```
   if (($handle = fopen("$source_file", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, $delemietr);
        if (!$columns) {
            $error['message'] = 'Empty';
             return ($error);
        }

        while (($rows = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "\t")) !== false) {
            if ($rows[1] && array(null) !== $rows) { // ignore blank lines
                        $data1 = $rows[1];
              }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hello there is porblem my csv has multi line and i want get only last line in fille

Comment: Then you need to add nested loop to get total lines & get last row data