# Read lines of CSV file and put values into an Array

Tags: php, csv, foreach

I have an CSV file with multiple lines, and each line has more then 50 values all separated by '|' and i want to store each of those values into an array.
The first line i get all values into the array with no problem, but the rest of the lines are passed into the array into a single key, for other words the rest of the lines dont break into those 50+ values.
I've tried [PHP read CSV file line by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361786/php-read-csv-file-line-by-lines) this already.

this is what i need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SALE
            [1] => FF
            [2] => 17750478
            [3] => 235
            [4] => 2018-01-27T22:16:56
            [5] => 2018-05-13T12:06:11
            [6] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SALE
            [1] => FF
            [2] => 10423478
            [3] => 1006352300
            [4] => 2018-01-27T22:16:56
            [5] => 2018-05-13T12:06:11
            [6] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SALE
            [1] => FF
            [2] => 1204578
            [3] => 1002362300
            [4] => 2018-01-27T22:16:56
            [5] => 2018-05-13T12:06:11
            [6] => 
        )

)
```

But i get :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SALE
            [1] => FF
            [2] => 17750478
            [3] => 235
            [4] => 2018-01-27T22:16:56
            [5] => 2018-05-13T12:06:11
            [6] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SALE|FF|10423478|1006352300|2018-01-27T22:16:56|2018-05-13T12:06:11........
```

I've done a test and i took out alot of the values i left only lik 8 or 9 and the array finally comes how i want, but my file has 50+ values for each line. Is there a limit for breaking the values of each line?
my code:

```
               $OrderLines = array();

                $file = fopen($InboundInno.$ACKFile, 'r');
                while (($line = fgetcsv($file, false, '|' )) !== FALSE) {
                     $OrderLines[] = $line;
                }
                fclose($file);
```

***EDIT***
I've notice that the last value of the first line(the only line that gets all values one by one) is getting a " in the last value. this loop add's a " on the last value of the first lane.

Comment: Can you include the first couple of lines of the CSV so it is possible to test.

Comment: I can't post them, they are too long to post here, i can post part of one if it helps. Anyone else has any ideias how to put this to work? Still cant pass all other lines to the array

Comment: ````SALE|FF|10478|10000|2018-01-27T22:16:56|2018-05-13T12:06:11|HFYXZL|TST26399682|26399682 |1|5|300|975.0|20.0|995.0|GBP|16-UPS Express|Credit Card-MAESTRO|https://rcs02-sales.fftech.info/pub/invoice.aspx?i=FrJ36DOSD511J4WlHrWlbxP cbeN5rAfaRyk6CU5TkXbsGPn5l+8UJg==&pdf=1&d=1;https://rcs02-sales.fftech.info/Download/Aw bPdf?siteId=11251&orderId=15089027;https://rcs02-sales.fftech.info/PUB/returnint.aspx?i =FrJ36DOSD511J4WlHrWlbxPcbeN5rAfaRyk6CU5TkXbsGPn5l+8UJg==&pdf=1&d=1|||||||||false|false |false|false|false|false|false|false|false|```` I cut like 20 or more values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i got it.

I dont know why, but this code adds a `"` to the final of each line in my file like i said before. Ofcourse i did a test with the enclosure `($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, '|', ' " ')` and nothing. 
Since i was desperate i inverted the enclosure and i did `($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, '|', " ' ")` and it works.
I don't know why PHP is treating the ' as a " but ok. Well it works now so hope this might help anyone in same situation. Here is full code:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, '|', "'")) !== FALSE) {

      $OrderLines[] = $line;
}
 fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this to read CSV file:

```
function csv_decode($csv){
    $output = array();
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);

     foreach($lines as $line){
        $output[] = explode('|', $line);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro but it still wont break all lines besides the first one

Comment: Could you please provide at least part, of the CSV file you are reading?

Comment: sure, this is ONE line.
````SALE|FF|10478|10000|2018-01-27T22:16:56|2018-05-13T12:06:11|HFYXZL|TST26399682|26399682 |1|5|300|975.0|20.0|995.0|GBP|16-UPS Express|Credit Card-MAESTRO|https://rcs02-saleh.info/pub/invoice.aspx?i=FrJ3&pdf=1&d=1|||||||||false|false |false|false|false|false|false|false|false|false|false|2|8379201|12132465|CLOTHING WOMEN'S FR|803454427|1473514G7042766|OS|false|975|1300|0|0|0||21|41.65|1|22|false|false|false|f alse|8000|Parfum|Flammable Liquids|Alcohols|None|50ml|false|false|false
````
I had to cut it, it has to many characters so stack dont allow me to post it